# Apt Update Error

Tags: apt, repository

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I've installed some things in the initial setup, but it was a lot, and I don't remember in which steps I messed up in order to `apt get update` give this error:

```
Get:48 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [4.712 B]     
Reading package lists... Done                                                                         
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04  Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1496576244
E: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04  Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How can I fix these errors?

Comment: You  can not fix this, you have to contact the maintainer of the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to download the key for `http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04` or you will have to disable it

In Ubuntu Software center you can go to the `edit` menu then select `software sources` and select the `other software` tab and remove it from there

or look at `/etc/apt/sources.list` and see if its listed there and comment it out "#" or delete the line/lines for that entry .. if you don't see it there look for it in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and find the file that line is located in and (it will probably be in a separate file) delete it.